# How to create an AMPScript Array or dynamic var?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Is it possible to create and use an array like in PHP or other scripting languages?

And/Or is there a way to generate dynamic variables so that you can loop thr

Such as:

```
for @cnt = 1 to 5 do
      Set @var@cnt  = Concat('someval',@cnt )
NEXT @cnt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best you can do for arrays in AMPScript is to use the buildrowset functions -- [**BuildRowSetFromString()**](https://ampscript.guide/BuildRowSetFromString) and [**BuildRowSetFromXML()**](https://ampscript.guide/BuildRowSetFromXML).  I have an proof-of-concept based on an XML rowset [**here on my blog**](https://sprignaturemoves.com/ca-xml/).

[**Server-Side JavaScript**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_syntaxGuide.htm) is also an option, but the Marketing Cloud folks don't recommend it for performance reasons.  It's at its best in landing pages and Microsites, but you can also use it in small-run emails without much trouble.

Comment: SSJS mainly falls over with data lookup.